# Short story about the invention of a zero gravity Blender

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Probably in *Asimov's* or *DAW World's Best*.

The story is about a guy with tech implants trying to invent a zero-gravity blender. One of his female co-workers takes his job 'cause he can’t afford any more upgrades (doesn’t want them anyway).

I recall it was a 3 speed blender ready for debut that day, but speed 3 didn't work. So instead of fixing the problem, and blowing the debut, he made them simply remove the speed 3 button and honor the deadline?

Comment: A blender like for drinks?

Comment: @OrganicMarble Given the mention of speeds, probably [this kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blender).

Answer (score 4):

It's only ever been published in [*Analog Science Fiction and Fact*, April 1999](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?56836), but I'm pretty sure you're describing "[The Company Man](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?86174)" by Kent Johnson.

**A guy with tech implants**

The protagonist is Dean Plummer, and he's wired, implanted and gene-modified.

> Before he was even conceived, Dean's parents made the difficult and expensive decision to have him genetically and neurologically enhanced. [...]
>
> Improved neurotransmitters were introduced, along with a network of organic microfiliments connected to a parallel biochip interface.  Nanotechnology was used to alter the structure of his developing nervous system, allowing access to areas of the brain that went unused in base humans.  A neural shunt was installed in his tiny skull, his future connection to a world of supercomputers, communications satellites and the VRNet.

**Trying to invent a zero-gravity blender**

Plummer is the director of marketing for a conglomerate named Martin-Matsuura, developing consumer products for commercial sale; he has previously delivered a zero-g toaster and a vacuum cleaner.

> "Instead of using rotating blades for mixing as in current blender designs-which don't work well in zero-g, by the way, because there's no gravity to pull the liquid into contact with the blades-our Sonic Blender uses ultrasonic sound waves for thorough blending no matter how the liquid is oriented in the blending chamber. [...]"

**Speed 3 didn't work**

> "The seals failed again," Innes said grimly.  "I dunno why, but as soon as we get the prototype up here in zero-g and run it on high speed for just a few seconds, the seals start oozing like crazy..."

**He made them simply remove the speed 3 button**

Close; instead of removing a button it's just rewired so it makes more noise on normal speed without actually running at high speed.

> "That was Erin's idea," Innes said sheepishly.  "She had me rewire the high speed switch into the normal speed circuit.  Then we installed a piezo beeper that just made it *sound* like the blender was running faster."

**One of his female co-workers takes his job**

> "I hear you've got some *other* news for me."
>
> "You must be referring to Ms. Barton-Higgins..."
>
> "Yeah, I hear she's getting my job."
>
> Virgo frowned with mock sincerity.  "Regrettably, we felt a change in management styles was in order.  Nothing against you personally, of course, but Ms. Barton-Higgins has... outperformed you of late."

**He can't afford any more upgrades**

Not quite; he *does* want to be upgraded so he can keep his job, he's just been deemed obsolete.

> "What about that upgrade you promised me?  That's all I need, then things'll be like the old days, you'll see."
>
> "I'm afraid that's the problem," Virgo said.  "Our engineers have determined that an upgrade wouldn't do you much good.  It seems your circuit architecture has become hopelessly outdated."